# Adding CSS to xslt with relative path

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an xml report which uses an .xslt file while opening it. This xslt file will contain css and images. My problem is, I want to add these files by using relative path. For now I gave the full path like below. For making my complete project as a jar, I cannot give the full path. Please suggest me how I could add these files without giving an absolute path:

My xml report is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href='D:\Project\OwnWorkspace\PDFAutomation\src\com\pdf\Resources\Report11.xsl' type='text/xsl'?>
<Report LastXMLNum="1" Env="" RunFlow="" BuildVersion="" XMLNum="1" DateTime="03-Feb-2014 01:13:54.339" PrevXMLFileName="" NextXMLFileName="" Instruction1="'Text in Green' - Text that is not present in the PDF under Test." Instruction2="'Text in Red' - Text that is not present in the Reference PDF">
  <TestCase ID="1" Desc="PDFSearchText" TCStatus="1" Row="1">
    <TestFlow ID="1" Desc="PDFSearchText">
      <TestActivity ID="1" Desc="Search Text">
```

Now my xslt will be as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
- <xsl:template match="/">
- <HTML>
- <HEAD>
  <LINK REL="StyleSheet" HREF="D:\Project\OwnWorkspace\PDFAutomation\src\com\pdf\Resources\Report.css" TYPE="text/css" /> 
<xsl:text />
```

In this .css file's path and Image's, I need to give relative path....because for making my project as a jar i need it to be a relative path so that i can make it jar with that content

Answer (score 0):

```
[cssFolder]/Report.css
[xslFolder]/Report11.xsl
```

in XML (assuming the xml is outside these folders):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href='[xslFolder]/Report11.xsl' type='text/xsl'?>
```

in stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
- <xsl:template match="/">
- <HTML>
- <HEAD>
  <LINK REL="StyleSheet" HREF="../[cssFolder]/Report.css" TYPE="text/css" />
```

Comment: I have already tried those two solutions. But there was no luck. The actual problem here is..I have created one xml reporting for my selenium project. I will generate xml through my java code. once my execution is done, for checking my reports i will open this xml. While opening the xml, it will use xslt for styles. This xslt will again use .css files and images for the report. I need to make the jar file of my code for which I have to use the relative path of my css images. If give absolute path there, while working with my jar file in the other system will cause the problem.pls suggest now.